# IMAP + Office365 + XOAUTH2: Is there any way to re-authenticate a new accessToken without disconnecting/reconnecting to the server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, office365, imap

So, last week my application that connects to Office365 using IMAP suddenly stopped working with Basic Authentication (gee, thanks for the early cut-off with no warning Microsoft).  I tried troubleshooting that issue for hours, and could find literally nothing wrong since everything was already configured to work with Basic Auth (and was working).  I do know they've been threatening to shut-off Basic Auth for a while now, and with a new looming deadline of October, 2022.

After getting nowhere with why it suddenly stopped working, I finally decided to just bite the bullet and switch to using the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.   After a day and a half of trial-and-error to put together the right series of incantations to make that work correctly, I got that working.   Microsoft's documentation is borderline garbage with conflicting information and confusing examples.   That and a complete lack of any reasonable error response from the IMAP server about why authentication failed (just the lovely "NO AUTHENTICATE failed" message).

Note: I am using the Client Credentials flow and the AccessToken is being issued to expire after 1 hour.

So, here's the question:
My app basically loops on IDLE and/or processing new mail.  When the AccessToken expires, the server will respond with a "Session invalidated - AccessTokenExpired" and then just close or reset the connection.   This does make sense, but I would prefer to keep the connection open and just re-authenticate.

My first idea was just re-issue the "AUTHENTICATE" command 1 minute before the AccessToken expired.  Server did not like that and gave me a "Command received in Invalid state." response.  Hrmph.

Second idea was 1 minute before the AccessToken expired, issue a "LOGOUT" and then "AUTHENTICATE" again.  However, Microsoft's IMAP server responds to the "LOGOUT" with "OK" and then closes the connection...  Hrmph.

```
C: R0001 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2
S: +
C: <username:token base64>
S: R0001 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
C: R0002 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4REV1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: R0002 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C: R0003 SELECT INBOX
... <59 mins later> ...
C: R0021 LOGOUT
S: * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server IMAP4 server signing off.
S: R0021 OK LOGOUT completed.
Connection closed.
```

I did notice there's a server capability called "BACKENDAUTHENTICATE", but there literally is no documentation that I could find on what the heck that capability is about or used for...

What I would really like to do is just issue something like "AUTHENTICATE" again, but with the new AccessToken and then go back to the IDLE/new mail loop.  Or maybe a "REAUTHENTICATE" command (that doesn't currently exist).
And yes, I have read RFC4959, RFC3501, and even RFC2222 (as well as a lot of SO posts).

For now, I have just accepted the fact that the connection is going to close and then I'll turn around and re-open a new one...

I would love to hear if anyone has any other bright ideas.
I am considering re-implementing the application using their Graph API, which might be the slightly better long-term option assuming we stay on Microsoft Office365.
I did like that IMAP was a more generic and broadly accepted mailbox protocol and why I chose it in the first place.

Comment: RFC3501 does not include any ability to reauthenticate an existing connection as it was not envisioned that an existing connection would become unauthenticated.  Just create a new one, unfortunately.  It's not that expensive.

Comment: I understand that the current list of RFC's did not foresee this shortcoming.  I find such limitations regularly.   However, when you are running on a server that is behind a NAT gateway and the server is processing a lot of connections for the primary application, you do have to be mindful of exhausting the pool of available TCP ports.   So, I would tend to disagree.  It can be expensive when connections are a finite shared resource.   I've since just moved the email processing onto it's own dedicated server so that is not a problem.

Comment: Note: just because IMAP is defined by an RFC(s), that does not mean implementors follow it exactly and/or don't add their own "enhancements".   Case in point: what the heck is the Microsoft's server capability "BACKENDAUTHENTICATE"?    I guess what I was looking for is whether Microsoft had some undocumented "enhancement" in their own implementation that perhaps handled a re-authenticate...

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer some of your questions.

> I do know they've been threatening to shut-off Basic Auth for a while now, and with a new looming deadline of October, 2022. After getting nowhere with why it suddenly stopped working

Microsoft says that in early 2022, they will pick tenants (using some unpublished criteria) and disable basic authentication for all the chosen protocols except SMTP AUTH for a period of between 12 and 48 hours. SMTP AUTH is excluded because it might affect important operational aspects like multi-functional devices or PowerShell scripts sending updates about a job’s progress. When the period expires, Microsoft will enable basic authentication automatically.

Please refer to this link : https://office365itpros.com/2021/09/24/basic-authentication-exchange/

The Basic Auth has been already disabled for many of my clients, so the above statement is valid.

> I am using the Client Credentials flow and the AccessToken is being issued to expire after 1 hour.

Using the Client Credentials flow, you do not get a refresh Token which can be used to get a valid Token without losing/dropping/closing the connection.

Based on the RFC6749 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3), a refresh Token should not be included.

As @Max mentioned in his comment, "RFC3501 does not include any ability to reauthenticate an existing connection".

Since you don't want to lose/close the connection, I would recommend to use the
Oauth2 authorization code flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which will give you a refresh Token as well.

Also, I would recommend to use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)

> The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) enables developers to acquire tokens from the Microsoft identity platform in order to authenticate users and access secured web APIs. It can be used to provide secure access to Microsoft Graph, other Microsoft APIs, third-party web APIs, or your own web API. MSAL supports many different application architectures and platforms including .NET, JavaScript, Java, Python, Android, and iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It helps explain the sudden dysfunction prior to the published cut-off date.

Comment: Interesting note about the refresh token.   Though, not sure how that would actually help since the connection is already established and authenticated, I still don't have a means to provide an updated/refreshed token (after getting one with the refresh token).   That would imply that performing a refresh and getting an updated token somehow causes the previous connection to continue to be authenticated.  I highly doubt that, but I have not tested whether doing that flow and getting a refresh token and then refreshing has that behavior.

Comment: As for using MSAL - this is code written in Ruby on a Unix platform.   MSAL currently has no support for that...    And my whole point of using IMAP was to NOT be tied to Microsoft.   If I'm going to rewrite anything, I will probably just change over to Microsoft Graph.